# Unable to proxy accountings via freeradius

Tags: proxy, radius

I have installed freeradius (version 3.0.13) on a VM and have performed basic configuration which seems to work fine. When I try to proxy accountings, this is the error that I get when I run `radiusd -CX`:

```
/etc/raddb/proxy.conf[36]: Unknown home_server "server1"
```

This is my actual configuration:

```
####proxy.conf####

proxy server {
 default_fallback = no
}

home_server server1{
 type = acct
 ipaddr = 10.194.128.105
 port = 1813
 secret = passme
 require_message_authenticator = no
 response_window = 20
 zombie_period = 40
 status_check = status-server
 check_interval = 30
 num_answers_to_alive = 3
 max_outstanding = 65536
}


home_server server2{
 type = acct
 ipaddr = 10.194.128.106
 port = 1813
 secret = passsme
 require_message_authenticator = no
 response_window = 20
 zombie_period = 40
 status_check = status-server
 check_interval = 30
 num_answers_to_alive = 3
 max_outstanding = 65536
}

home_server_pool freeradius_loadbalance {
 type = fail-over
 home_server = server1
 home_server = server2
}

realm NULL {
 auth_pool = freeradius_loadbalance
 nostrip
}
```

When I change `type = acct` to `type = auth` or `type = auth+acct`, I can start radius without issues.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hello ,I am updating with the error: { /etc/raddb/proxy.conf[36]: Unknown home_server "server1". }

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add details. I’ve done it for you already this time.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by ,simply, replacing *auth_pool = freeradius_loadbalance* to *acct_pool = freeradius_loadbalance* in the **proxy.conf** .

Thanks :)